# Issue watchers not receiving email notifications on JIRA software

Tags: jira

**Issue watchers not receiving email notifications on JIRA software :** I have watched several issue on our JIRA software, However I am not receiving any email when there is an update going on. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the notification scheme applied to your project. As a project admin, you're capable to see the notification rules. For Jira Server, you can check this link: https://jira_domain/plugins/servlet/project-config/PROJECTKEY/notifications

You might need to check with your Jira administrator to adjust the notification scheme.

Also bear in mind, if you update a Jira issue by yourself, you might not be getting notifications by default. See your Preferences under your profile:
https://jira_domain/secure/ViewProfile.jspa
*(My Changes: Do not notify me)*

Another potential problem might be watchers' e-mail addresses - are they correct? Is your SMTP server able to send e-mails to these watchers' addresses? Problems might typicallly happen if recipients' e-mail addresses are in different domain and your SMTP is not configured properly to send e-mails to external domains.